# Integrating monomials over $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ - Folland

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, gaussian-integral

This is an exercise from Folland: Suppose $f(x)=\prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{\alpha_j}$ where all $\alpha_j$ are even. Then show that
$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} f d \sigma= \frac{2 \prod_{j=1}^{n}\Gamma(\beta_j)}{\Gamma\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_j\right)} \quad \text{where }\beta_j=\frac{\alpha_j+1}{2}$$.

As hint Folland suggests to calculate $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|^2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Attempt: By Tonelli's we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|^2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\prod_{j=1}^{n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}y^{\alpha_j} \mathrm{d}y=\prod_{j=1}^{n}\Gamma(\beta_j)$$

I think I am supposed to change to polar coordinates now $(r=|x|, \, x'=\frac{x}{|x|})$. Since $f(rx')=r^{\sum \alpha_j}f(x')$, we get:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}\Gamma(\beta_j)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|^2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-r^2}r^{(\sum \alpha_j)+n-1}\mathrm{d}r \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} f \mathrm{d}\sigma$$ from which the result follows.

Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. The main idea is to find and auxiliary function $u(x)=A(|x|)B(|x|^{-1}x)$ ($A$ is radial, $B$ depends only on direction, i.e. is defined on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$). Polar coordinates uncouple $A$ and $B$ into more tractable integrals: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(x)\,dx=\big(\int^\infty_0 A(r)r^{n-1}\,dr\big)\big(\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}B(w)\,\sigma_{n-1}(dw)\big)$. The $u$ id chosen so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}u(x)\,dx$ is easy to estimate.